# Which number, 0 or 1, should I define the variabliable of loops for arrays from?

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm a beginner in data structures. I learnt that SqLists are starting from 1, when the arrays inside SqLists are from 0.
**The question is** if I create a loop, which of the following representation is better? Will the other one be weird?

```c
//i=0 according to arrays
for(int i=0;i<L->length;++i)
L->data[i]=givenArray[i];
```

```c
//i=1 according to SqList
for(int i=1;i<=L->length;++i)
L->data[i-1]=givenArray[i-1];
```

Comment: Which requires the least amount of effort to write?

Comment: What are "SqLists"?

Comment: Thanks! Because for me, the second one is remarkably better to avoid mistakes of looping times, however, no book can i find defines in the same way. That's why i wonder if there are unwritten rules.

Comment: 'Sequential List', sorry for ambiguity

Comment: A good optimizing C compiler might generate the same object code for both versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with either ways.
With that aside, the first way of writing is more clear and often used when writing programs (in any language).

If you are programming alone, it doesn't really matter, just pick your style and stick to it.
But, if you want to adhere to global programming conventions, and make your code more readable and accessible to other people, stick for the first style.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This gives me the reason why i cannot find any book starting from i=1!